# Will UA741CN as a comparator work below 8V?

Tags: comparator

I wanted to create a comparator circuit with UA741CN which is only comparator/op-amp I have in my junk right now. I wanted to use it with 5V but no matter what is inverting ref voltage is giving any voltage to non-inverting output gives me always high as output. When I set the power supply to the 8V it works as it should be. Even in 7V it is acting weirdly as i said so. What might be the problem here?

Comment: Did you check the 741 datasheet for its (minimum) power voltage(s) requirements?

Comment: The 741 can't operate on a single 5V supply.  It needs its inputs and outputs to all stay a couple of volts away from the power rails.  Leaves you with very little to work with at 5V.

Comment: I hooked up 10V for V+ and 0V for V- but max 5V for inverting and non-inverting inputs? These two inputs are also included in Supply Voltage range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the datasheet for the [device](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf) ...the device is unsuitable for your purpose.

[image]

The recommended minimum supply voltage is +/-10 V.

Comment: Actually I tryed this; I supplied 10V to the V+ and 0V to the V- and through voltage divider to the inverting input and connected a potantiometer to the non-inverting input. Still acting abnormal. Is the Supply Voltage information in the datasheet refers also for the inverting and non-inverting inputs? Or just for V+/V-?

Comment: @user3554877 The supply voltages are V+ and V-. Usually the inverting and non-inverting inputs of an op amp must not exceed the supply voltages. Page 4 of the linked datasheet confirms that's the case for this op amp.

Comment: I should probably buy a 5V suitable op-amp or comparator.

Comment: @Bciceksoy ±10 does not mean "approximately 10". It means "+10 **and** -10". So +10 on the V+ supply **and** -10 on the V- supply.

Comment: For clarification: ±10V means a total supply voltage of 20V between the positive and negative supply rails, regardless of where "ground" is.